# MobX: context is lost during fetch execution

Tags: mobx

I am writing the fetchPosts method using ModX, but I get an error related to the fact that inside fetchPosts *this* is undefined, although I use the arrow function. How to fix this behavior?

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx"

class Todo {
  todos = []

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }

  fetchTodos() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => this.todos.concat(json))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e))
  }
}

export default new Todo()
```

using chrome devtools it is output that this in the method becomes undefined

Comment: How do you invoke it? Can you add that part?

Comment: `import todo from "./store/todo"
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"

const App = observer(() => {
  return <button onClick={todo.fetchTodos}>Fetch</button>
})

export default App`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context is lost because your function is not an arrow function and you pass it like that `onClick={todo.fetchTodos}`, it's not related to MobX or React, it's just how Javascript works

To fix it you can make it an arrow function:

```
class Todo {
  todos = []

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }

  // Make it an arrow function here
  fetchTodos = () => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => this.todos.concat(json))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e))
  }
}
```